# Syntax highlighting is lost after collapsing and expanding the revision history

Tags: bug, revisions-list, syntax-highlighting

When I visit https://sometopic.stackexchange.com/posts/postId/revisions and click on ▼ to collapse the revision and then ▶ to expand, the syntax highlighting is lost after some milliseconds. After collapsing and expanding once syntax highlighting is lost forever, i.e., until a refresh.

Example on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/):

[image: Example on [Stack Overflow]]

Example on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com):

[image: Example on [Ask Ubuntu]]

Comment: If you're not on the first revision, you can change between the Inline and Side-by-side  buttons to bring the syntax highlighting back. "Side-by-side Markdown" doesn't show syntax highlighting.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Good observation. Some network activity takes place before the syntax highlighting disappear. And that also occurs when brought back by switching views, i.e., inline and side-by-side.